# facebook caches og:title?

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnetworks.co.id%2Fblog.php%3Fid%3D2

the problem is that facebook does read my url rightly like this

[image]

ok everything goes fine untill i scroll and check my like button on my page.

[image]

do facebook cache them ? or there is a better explanation.

thanks for the time looking in :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely a matter of caching, just try to add a dummy parameter to your URL to *fool* facebook and you'll [see](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnetworks.co.id%2Fblog.php%3Fid%3D2%26123). :-)

For you and @Michael Irigoyen, it's always a good practice to do this whenever you feel that FB is showing something you didn't expect OR if by mistake (or intentionally) you clicked on the share button and the page was not 100% ready to publish. And trust me this happens A LOT! ;-)

Comment: You can clear the cache without fooling Facebook by using the Facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug Insert your url, let the debugger scrape your page and the cache is cleared.

Comment: You can do it programatically as well by making a post request to graph URL.
This might help http://alfanso.com/asking-facebook-to-clear-cached-data/

Answer (score 2):

Actually facebook scrapes the pages and updates the cache every 24 hours https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo.

Comment: Running something through the [Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) should empty the cache, though — and the Linter is what is producing that output for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've come to find that Facebook does indeed cache the all the `<og:*>` tags the first time it's shared on Facebook. I ran into a similar issue when creating a "Share to Facebook" link on our website. I was trying to tweak the title and the description to be exactly how I wanted and I'd always have to change the knowledge base article I was working with to one I hadn't shared previously to see the changes I had made.

That being said, I have no clue for how long Facebook keeps that stuff in cache. I didn't do any sort of testing on that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a cache related problem. But the reason could rely in the fact that you are limited to change the og:title, you can do it before you reach the 50 likes, so I think that facebook keeps a history in case you try to change the title after the limit becomes reached.

Of course, this is only a supposition.